# Descriptive Hapi/Joi validation error

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, hapi.js, joi

I've been trying to implement Joi in our node application (joi as standalone, not with hapi) and it seems to validate the schema properly but the error is always the same

```
[ValidationError: value must be an object] 
name: 'ValidationError',
details:
[ { message: 'value must be an object',
   path: 'value',
   type: 'object.base',
   context: [Object] } ],
_object:.....
```

I never get the specifics on which key it failed on and description of why it failed.

this is a sample schema I'm using:

```
exports.workersSchema =
{
workers: joi.array({
    id: joi.string().alphanum(),
    wID: joi.object({
        idValue: joi.string().alphanum()
    }),
    person: {
        governmentIDs: joi.array({itemID: joi.string().alphanum()}),
        legalName: joi.object({
            givenName: joi.string(),
            middleName: joi.string(),
            preferredSalutations: joi.array(
                {
                    salutationCode: {
                        longName: joi.string()
                    }

                }
            ),
            preferredName: joi.object().keys({
                FormattedName: joi.string()
            }),
        }),
        birthDate: joi.string().alphanum()
    }
})
}
```

And this is the json object I'm sending :

```
{"workers" : [        
        {
          "id" : "",
          "wID" : {
            "idValue" : ""
          },
          "person" : {
            "governmentIDs":[{
                "itemID": "asd" 
            }],
            "legalName":{
              "givenName" : "PA",
              "middleName" : "",
              "preferredSalutations" : [{
                "salutationCode" : {
                  "longName" : ""
                    }
              }],
              "preferredName" : {
                "FormattedName" : ""
              },
              "birthDate" : ""
        }]
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I even tried to follow something on the blog and while the examples were showing detailed info I never got anything besides

```
"value must be an object"
```

It validates it correctly but when it sees a misfit value it just gives that error and nothing else.

Also, if you look at the 'wID' section it has a 'idValue' object but when I get rid of the idValue and just put a alphanum right on the wID key, it also passes the validation.

ps. When validating keys that are objects. Do I have to validate it with

```
key: Joi.object({
  a:Joi.string()
})
```

or can I just do?:

```
key: {
  a:Joi.string()
}
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Can you please give an example of an object that you're trying to validate against so we can try it ourselves and perhaps modify the schema to suit?

Comment: That object is not a valid JavaScript object. You're missing some closing } brackets

Comment: `var obj = {
  "workers" : [{
    "id" : "",
    "wID" : {
      "idValue" : ""
    },
    "person" : {
      "governmentIDs":[{
        "itemID": "asd" 
      }],
      "legalName":{
        "givenName" : "PA",
        "middleName" : "",
        "preferredSalutations" : [{
          "salutationCode" : {
            "longName" : ""
          }
        }],
        "preferredName" : {
          "FormattedName" : ""
        },
      },
      "birthDate" : ""
    }
  }]
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a couple of issues. First of all, make sure that the object you're validating against is indeed an `object` with a `workers` key. The validation seems to be suggesting that you're not providing an object for this base value (an array perhaps)?

Also in a few instances I think you're using the API incorrectly (e.g. `joi.array(...)` is not valid). I've modified your schema to work how I think you intended. If not, post a sample object and I'll amend.

```
var schema = {
    workers: Joi.array().required().includes({
        id: Joi.string().alphanum(),
        wID: {
            idValue: Joi.string().alphanum()
        },
        person: {
            governmentIDs: Joi.array().includes(Joi.string().alphanum()),
            legalName: {
                givenName: Joi.string(),
                middleName: Joi.string(),
                preferredSalutations: Joi.array().includes(Joi.string()),
                preferredName: {
                    formattedName: Joi.string()
                },
            },
            birthDate: Joi.string().alphanum()
        }
    })
};
```

Here's a valid object for that schema:

```
var goodExample = {
    workers: [
        {
            id: 'bhdsf78473',
            wID: {
                idValue: 'idvalue1'
            },
            person: {
                governmentIDs: ['id1', 'id2'],
                legalName: {
                    givenName: 'Johnny',
                    middleName: 'Michael',
                    preferredSalutations: ['sir', 'Dr'],
                    preferredName: {
                        formattedName: 'Sir Johnny Michael Smith'
                    }
                },
                birthDate: '2411986'
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Here's an invalid one:

```
var badExample = {
    workers: [
        {
            id: 'bhdsf7^£$%^£$%8473',   // Here's the issue
            wID: {
            },
            person: {
                governmentIDs: ['id1', 'id2'],
                legalName: {
                    givenName: 'Johnny',
                    middleName: 'Michael',
                    preferredSalutations: ['sir', 'Dr'],
                    preferredName: {
                        formattedName: 'Sir Johnny Michael Smith'
                    }
                },
                birthDate: '2411986'
            }
        }, 
    ], 
};
```

Joi should give nice detailed output for `Joi.assert(example, schema);`:

```
$ node index.js

/.../node_modules/Joi/lib/index.js:121
            throw new Error(message + error.annotate());
                  ^
Error: {
  "workers": [
    {
      "wID": {},
      "person": {
        "governmentIDs": [
          "id1",
          "id2"
        ],
        "legalName": {
          "givenName": "Johnny",
          "middleName": "Michael",
          "preferredSalutations": [
            "sir",
            "Dr"
          ],
          "preferredName": {
            "formattedName": "Sir Johnny Michael Smith"
          }
        },
        "birthDate": "2411986"
      },
      "id" [1]: "bhdsf7^£$%^£$%8473"
    }
  ]
}

[1] workers at position 0 fails because id must only contain alpha-numeric characters
    at root.assert (/.../node_modules/Joi/lib/index.js:121:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../index.js:57:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

**NOTE:** This answer is using Joi 5.1.2 (API: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v5.1.0/README.md). `Joi.array().includes()` will be dropped in the next release in favour of `Joi.array().items()`

---

The object that you posted is not a valid JavaScript object because it's missing some closing } brackets. Here's the valid version:

```
var obj = {
  "workers" : [{
    "id" : "",   // <-------- Shouldn't be empty
    "wID" : {
      "idValue" : ""
    },
    "person" : {
      "governmentIDs":[{
        "itemID": "asd" 
      }],
      "legalName":{
        "givenName" : "PA",
        "middleName" : "",
        "preferredSalutations" : [{
          "salutationCode" : {
            "longName" : ""
          }
        }],
        "preferredName" : {
          "FormattedName" : ""
        },
      },
      "birthDate" : ""
    }
  }]
};
```

If I validate that with my provided schema, I get the following message (using Joi 5.1.0):

```
[1] workers at position 0 fails because id is not allowed to be empty
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed information! I added my object and funnily enough I can never get that detailed error. no matter what I set the schema to with the simplest json structure. Hope the example helps

Comment: Thank you!! I finally noticed the error on my end, I didn't have joi.array().REQUIRED().includes()... But does that force the object to have values for all keys??

Comment: @KoalaD No the required doesn't cascade. It only means that the `workers` key of the root object must contain an array. Which it should, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. I was only asking because errors are mentioning about fields being empty but all I have is Joi.string(). Strangely it doesn't error out on all keys but on some keys. It does seem like it cascades down once I put the required()... hmmm